# Show that if <S1;S2,s> => * s', it is not necessarily the case that <S1,s> =>* s'

Tags: programming-languages, operational-semantics

I am studying Structural Semantics for programming languages and I have come to this proof that I can not achieve.

[image: Structural Op semantics for while]

Whith these rules plus Splitting and No interference, I am trying to get a proof.

I tried:

```
s0 in State
<S1,s> =>* s0

Stm0 in Stm
<Stm0, s0> =>* <S2,s'>
```

And somehow put S2 inside Stm0, but it does not make sense and can not get it to work.

I am sure it is something related to an intermediate state and make S2 jump to <S2,s'> from that state.

EDIT:

Hi, I did the following:

```
S1 = Skip, so
<Skip,s> => s
then
<Skip;S2,s> => <S2,s>, for s'=s
```

Can this serve as a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you give is a counterexample of the reciprocal. That is, you're giving an example where $\langle S_1, s\rangle \Rightarrow^* s'$ but not $\langle S_1; S_2, s\rangle \Rightarrow^* s'$.

To prove the original statement, you would need to find an $s'$ such that $\langle S_1; S_2, s\rangle \Rightarrow^* s'$ but $\langle S_1, s\rangle \Rightarrow^* s'$ does not hold. For example, if $S_1 = \text{Skip}$ that means choosing $s'$ such that $\langle S_2, s\rangle \Rightarrow^* s'$ but $s' \not\Rightarrow^* s$.

I'm not sure about the particulars of your language, but if $s = \{x \mapsto 1, a \mapsto 2\}$, $s' = \{x \mapsto 2, a \mapsto 2\}$ and $S_2 = x := a$ then the required condition to holds.

Comment: Gracias @Carlos Miguel Soto. I was getting confused and you gave a proper example. Thanks!